# PHP/mySQL and Google Maps Geocoding

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, google-maps

Basically what I have is a sql database with various data points in it (name, email, etc.) and importantly fields that contain addresses. What I am attempting to do is use these addresses (possibly just the zip codes?) to plot pins on a google map with their geocoding system. I know that i need to collect all of the zips from the database in an array and do some sort of foreach for every zip but I am unsure of how to do this. Here is what I have so far, can anyone help me?

```
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect('my_database_host.edu','my_database_user','my_database_password');

if (!$dbh)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
mysql_select_db('my_database_name', $dbh);

$query = "SELECT fldZip FROM tblLocation";
$findzips = mysql_query($query);
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($findzips)) {
    echo $row['fldZip'];
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

}

  function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:90%;top:30px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the Javascript-API to geocode the ZIPs use the [geocoding-webservice](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) via PHP.

That also would be a good point to store the LatLng's inside the DB, so you don't have to request them again.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that there was a PHP Google Maps Geocoding service, I'll have to look into that, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to geocode addresses from a MySQL db. So, I am posting my solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      club:
      {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png' 
      },
      church:
      {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png' 
      }
    };

      function initialize() 
      {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.976178, 23.735881),
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        <?php header("content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
        $getpoints = "SELECT lat, lng, name, address, type FROM markers";

        if(!$result = $con->query($getpoints)){
        die('There was an error running the query 
        [' . $con->error . ']');
        }

        else 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $thematic = "'$row[type]'";
                $name = "'$row[name]'";
                $map_address = "$row[address]";

                $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".urlencode($map_address);
                $lat_long = get_object_vars(json_decode(file_get_contents($url)));

                // pick out what we need (lat,lng)
                $lat_long = $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lat . "," . $lat_long['results'][0]->geometry->location->lng;

                echo "var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng($lat_long); 
                var icon = customIcons[$thematic] || {};
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                position: myLatlng1, 
                map: map,
                icon: icon.icon,
                title: '$map_address'
                });";           
            }
        }       

        ?>    
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

The address is the address field from the database.